# Open dialog with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog referenced by *$imageDialog* and I'm trying to open it with `$imageDialog.dialog("open")`, but it doesn't work.

The problem is that, by debugging, I've seen the `$imageDialog.dialog("open")` line executing, but then the open function inside *$imageDialog* does not execute. It doesn't show any errors and I checked that *$imageDialog* has the reference well set when executing the `$imageDialog.dialog("open")`.

Here is the html dialog:

```
<div class="dialog" id="image-dialog"></div>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
var selectedImage;
var $imageDialog = $("#image-dialog");

$imageDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Cerrar",
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-close"
            },
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ],
    maxHeight: 580,
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "top", at: "top+160" },
    resizable: false,
    title: "Vista de imagen",
    width: 1000,
    close: function() {
        $imageDialog.empty();
    },
    open: function() {
        content += "         <img alt='previsualizacion'" + "src='" + imageSrc + "'>";

        $imageDialog.append(content);
    }
});

function showImage(img) {
    selectedImage = img.src;
    console.log($imageDialog);
    $imageDialog.dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: try setting it's height as you do with width

Comment: Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

To open JQuery UI dialog just use:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">

</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/4/)

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Cerrar",
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-close"
            },
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ],
    maxHeight: 580,
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "top", at: "top+160" },
    resizable: false,
    title: "Vista de imagen",
    width: 1000,
    close: function() {
        $imageDialog.empty();
    },
    open: function() {
        content += "         <img alt='previsualizacion" + "src='" + imageSrc + "'>";

        $imageDialog.append(content);
    }
});

function showImage(img) {
    selectedImage = img.src;
    console.log($imageDialog);
    $imageDialog.dialog("open");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dialog" id="dialog">Dialog</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three thing you need to fix in your code

1. You have added modal html with id calibration-image-dialog but you are using #image-dialog in your script.
2. imageSrc is not defined
3. In modal Open event callback you have a single quote missing.

`content += "<img alt='previsualizacion" + "src='" + imageSrc + "'>";`

it should be

```
content += "<img alt='previsualizacion'" + "src='" + imageSrc + "'>";
```

Here is working demo .

```js
var $imageDialog, imageSrc;
$(function() {

  $imageDialog = $("#image-dialog");
  $imageDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Cerrar",
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-close"
      },
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }],
    maxHeight: 580,
    modal: true,
    position: {
      my: "top",
      at: "top+160"
    },
    resizable: false,
    title: "Vista de imagen",
    width: 500,
    close: function() {
      $imageDialog.empty();
    },
    open: function() {
      var content = "         <img alt='previsualizacion'" + "src='" + imageSrc + "'>";

      $imageDialog.html(content);

    }

  });
});

function showImage(img) {
  imageSrc = img.src;
  $imageDialog.dialog("open");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="dialog" id="image-dialog"></div>

<img onclick="showImage(this)" alt ="image" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/100000/velka/autumn-by-the-lake.jpg#.WLnFxbbRDek.link" width="100" height="100">

<img onclick="showImage(this)" alt ="image" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/40000/nahled/lion-head-portrait.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: I've edited my question, solving the point number 3 where i missed asingle quote and added the declaration of point number 2 (i had the declaration in my code but forgot to copy it here). In regards to point number 1, i don't really understand what you mean (i'm quite newbie), ¿could you provide som documentation about it, or something similar? Thanks for the help

Comment: You define dialog html (div tag) with a id of "calibration-image-dialog", But when you initialize your dialog in your javascript code you are using id #image-dialog instead of  #calibration-image-dialog this is what i try to explain in point 1.

Comment: what is unfixed now ?